# ServiceM8 API endpoints for job duration and booking datetime

Tags: servicem8

We are using ServiceM8.com.au's API and are a bit lost figuring out the exact API fields that are for the following data:

- job's duration
- job's booking date
- job's booking time

We obviously went through here: https://developer.servicem8.com many times, but it is unclear which fields to use as the fields we have tried did not do us any good.

What are the API fields/endpoints for these data points?

Answer (score 0):

You are after the endpoint jobactivity
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/jobactivity.json
If it is a scheduled job it will have the field activity_was_scheduled == 1
At the end is a copy of the json I get when I look up the last plumbing job I had scheduled to do today.   You will need 'start_date' and 'end_date'
You will also need job_uuid I would reckon, so search for that first in the 'job' endpoint.
I use $filter= generated_job_id eq 'whatever job number is'
It actually comes out like this: $filter=generated_job_id%20eq%2027183427
Complete query like:
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job.json?$filter= generated_job_id eq '1834'
Now you will have job_uuid from that query return json.
So now do query like:
https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/jobactivity.json?$filter= job_uuid eq '850209a9-b346-49ae-9299-207d9c7954cb'
The result json below shows job was for today 11/10/2023 from 12:30 PM till 3:30 PM

```
{  
    "uuid": "f26d3170-3618-444d-9cf1-207d9ae116db",  
    "start_date": "2023-10-11 12:30:00",  
    "end_date": "2023-10-11 15:30:00",  
    "active": 1,  
    "activity_was_recorded": 0,  
    "edit_by_staff_uuid": "f81bcd0e-7f42-46dc-aeb7-8b875011af9b",  
    "edit_date": "2023-10-11 12:01:41",  
    "job_uuid": "850209a9-b346-49ae-9299-207d9c7954cb",  
    "staff_uuid": "f81bcd0e-7f42-46dc-aeb7-8b875011af9b",  
    "activity_was_scheduled": 1,  
    "has_been_opened": 1,  
    "has_been_opened_timestamp": "2023-10-11 12:01:41",  
    "travel_time_in_seconds": "0",  
    "travel_distance_in_meters": "0",  
    "material_uuid": "",  
    "activity_was_automated": 0,  
    "allocated_timestamp": "2023-10-11 12:01:41",  
    "allocated_by_staff_uuid": "f81bcd0e-7f42-46dc-aeb7-8b875011af9b"  
  }
```